# What do these parameters mean in the makeifle that generated by cubemx?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, arm, stm32

I am learning and trying to write a makefile for a cortex based Holtek's chip. I intend to modify the makefile generated by cubemx for STM32 as a template, but I am not particularly familiar with GCC and make tools.

Now I'm studying this part.

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
```

I don't know what the parameters `-Wa`,`-a`,`-ad` and `alms` mean. I checked the GCC manual, but only found [the  description](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Assembler-Options.html#index-Wa) of `-Wa`:

> -Wa,option
>
> Pass option as an option to the assembler. If option contains
> commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

And I can't understand its real function from this description.

What do they mean?

Should I modify it in the makefile of Holtek chip?

Comment: Running `gcc -Wa,-a` is the same as running `as -a`.  You need to read the manual page `man as` to see what `-a` means to the assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Tom V, the first parameter `-Wa` is used to send the subsequent parameters `-a,-ad,-alms` to the assembler compiler (GAS).

The arguments `-a`,`-ad`, and `-alms` are used to generate listing files (those `.lst` files you find in build output directory) during compilation.

Listing files are useful to understand low-level details of your code after being compiled.

You can find more details about these options (and others)here:

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_2.html#SEC10

and here:

https://www.systutorials.com/generate-a-mixed-source-and-assembly-listing-using-gcc/

> Should I modify it in the makefile of Holtek chip?

No need to change, but you can omit these parameters if you want to compile a bit faster (not really  a great difference in my setup).